# Command prompt error while running an applet

Tags: java, applet, command-prompt

When I am trying to run an applet in command prompt I am getting an error message saying:

```
System cannot find the file specified.
```

Initially I compiled my applet, it works fine using:

```
javac BubbleSort1.java
```

But when I tried running this using the following, I'm getting the above error:

```
appletviewer BubbleSort1.html
```

Anyhow, both the html file and the java file are in same folder in C drive. (Windows 7) 
I would be grateful if anyone could help me.

The HTML is:

```html
<HTML> <TITLE> BubbleSort </TITLE> 
<BODY> 
<applet code=BubbleSort1.class name=BubbleSort1 width=700 height=330 VIEWASTEXT> 
</applet> 
</BODY> 
</HTML>
```

Comment: You're going to have to give a lot more details than that if you want anybody to be able to help you.  Please edit your question and provide the exact commands you're using, including the paths where the files are stored

Comment: How is the class file referenced inside the HTML?

Comment: Code here:<HTML>
<TITLE>
BubbleSort
</TITLE>
<BODY>

 <applet
  code=BubbleSort1.class
  name=BubbleSort1
  width=700
  height=330  VIEWASTEXT>
 </applet>

</BODY>
</HTML>

Comment: And is the class file in the same directory as the HTML file?

Comment: Yes! Both html and CLASS FILE are in same directory!

Comment: Then I'm sorry, I'm out of ideas.  If you're running appletviewer from the directory that has BubbleSort1.html and BubbleSort1.class, then I can't see any reason why it wouldn't find them both, and display the applet.  Sorry.

Comment: Does the source code of `BubbleSort1` begin with a `package` declaration?